# magento 1.9.2.4 row total price in negative(minus) after shopping cart discount

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

Magento 1.9.2.4 in admin row total price is in minus after shopping cart discount -

1 - Product tier price - [image: this is product tier price charts]

2 - Product price with quantity -

[image]

3 - Checkout -

[image]

4 - Admin row total - [image]

5 - Discount amount(percent of product price discount) is 10%

in admin row total is in "Minus", we are getting row total price in "Minus"

Please tell me how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your given screenshot Discount amount is set as **$318.50** which is wrong.

Formula works fine like 
Subtotal: $105.00
-(minus)Discount Amount: $318.50
Row Total = -$213.50

Did you made any changes in phtml file for Discount amount? issue is in discount amout. You need to check from where **$318.50** this amount has been came.

Comment: did you know from which file discount amount present ?

Comment: In default theme its coming from

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml file.

Might be some have changes the file in theme folder or you are using custom module then need to check according to it.

Comment: @sumeetbajaj Got any solution?

Comment: thanks buddy finally i got solution there is an extension for custom discount after placing order.

Comment: That's Great!! Please upvote the answer so it will be helpful for others also.